# Problems for drawing with canvas in scrollview

Tags: android, canvas, scrollview

I can add a editText to the scrollview and any other component but when I try to insert a drawing canvas, nothing appears. I show the code for more information

```
package prueba.android.ondraw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Prueba_ondrawActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        MyView v = new MyView(this);

        layout.addView(v);

    }
    private class MyView extends View{
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int j = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                int ancho= canvas.getWidth();
                String ancho2 = "" + ancho;
                Log.e(LOGTAG,ancho2);
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0,200,200, paint);
                j= j+100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        > 
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope that someone can give me a solution because it can not find how to draw within the scrollview

Thanksss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing nothing because your custom view has no size. 
Either use LayoutParams or pass in the pixel size directly. You could also implement `onMeasure` Some more info is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

```
layout.addView(v,300,300);
```

Also you don't need to call super.onDraw or create a new Paint on every iteration.

Comment: Hi, i have same problem as yours. its not solving. What is the solution. What t write in onMeasure method?

Comment: this worked for me where I was creating a canvas element and drawing on it and then I needed to set the size when I called addview() previously I was calling it without he width and height properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to draw and show it then you can put an ImageView in the ScrollView and display it like this:

```
newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.drawSomething();
imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you, this should be added, or should replace it with something? Do it under with canvas.drawSomething ();? I do not understand well how to apply his solution to my problem

Comment: This would be a way to do it without making a custom view.
What you will need to do is put a imageView in the scrollview (in your xml file) and make a method called whatever you like and put the code in there. Basically you create a blank bitmap and you can draw on that.